# How can I use an accumulator in a while loop

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that takes input from the user and then multiplies that input by 10. This input is then added to an accumulator whose initial value is `acc=0.0`. This repeats until the `acc` reaches < 100. I am not sure if there are other ways to do it, but for now I want to use the while loop for this. Below is what I have done so far. But not quite there. I know Im having trouble digesting the while loop concept.

```
condition=100
number = input("Enter your number: ")
number = int(number)*10
acc=0.0
while acc <= condition:
    number1 = input("Next number: ")
    number1 = int(number1)*10
    acc = number1 + number
    print("The summed value is", acc)
```

Comment: Update: I changed to "while acc < condition"
All the suggestions provided so far are useful. Only one other concern: When the loop exits, the accumulator includes the number that caused the loop to exit. To clarify what I mean, please see following run:

Your number: 5
Your number: 2
Your number: 4
Current sum: 110

whereas, I had actually wanted "Current sum: 70"

Comment: Post the updates as edit to the question, otherwise it would be hard for others to check it. Also, for your question, after the loop exits you can do `acc = acc - number1` which should give you the result you want

Answer (score 4):

You are not really adding to the accumulator, in each iteration you are setting the accumulator to number1 + number. Do

```
acc = acc + number1
```

instead, or `acc += number1`, which is equivalent.

Also, you should almost never have variable names like number and number1, but that's another thing.

Answer (score 3):

Few issues I see in your code -

1. You may not need the first `input` that is outside the while loop.
2. Inside your while loop, you are accumulating the numbers like - `acc = number1 + number` , this would add `number` and `number1` to acc in every loop (not accumulate) , I do not think that is what you want , maybe you want something like - `acc = acc + number1` this would add `acc` to itself and store it in itself. Or the shorter notation - `acc += number1`.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is in the accumulator assignment after taking number1 input. You keep assigning number and number1 to accumulator.

Here's the working code:

```
condition=100
number = input("Enter your number: ")
number = int(number)*10
acc = number
while acc <= condition:
        number1 = input("Next number: ")
        number1 = int(number1)*10
        acc = acc + number1
        print("The summed value is", acc)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
condition = 100
acc = 0

while acc <= condition:
    n = input("Your number: ")
    acc += int(n) * 10
    print("Current sum: {0}".format(acc))
```

Don't forget to accumulate it actually ;)